# unittest is not working

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, selenium

I am trying to run a test using unit test by using `python3 functional_tests.py` -the file name-   but i get

"----------------------------------------------------------------------

Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK"

here is my code:
from selenium import webdriver
    import unittest

```
class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def testcan_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        self.assertIn('To-Do', self.browser.title)
        self.fail('finish test')
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

i am using python 3.5.2

Comment: that code should work.  how are you executing it?  please update your question with the full command you used.

Comment: done .. i use `python3 functional_tests.py`

Comment: Your `if __name__ == '__main__'` block is indented, making it part of the class - it will never be executed.

Comment: I think the test class was not discoverable, either jasonharper answer, or try changing the class name into `TestNewVisitor(unittest.TestCase)` to make it discoverable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing the exercises in Test-Driven Development with Python? Are these Django tests? If they are Django tests, you can try the following:

```
python3 manage.py test functional_tests
```

Even so, the commenter states correctly that the `if __name`... portion of the code should not be indented. It should be fully on the left margin.